# How to write a shell that can switch to bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, go

I want to switch to the bash shell from my custom shell in go.

I am not sure how to sleep my parent process (custom shell) and switch to the child process (bash)

This is my part of the code.

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "/bin/bash")
    stdoutStderr, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdoutStderr)
```

I want to do it as follows:

```sh
myshell >> /bin/bash
$ /bin/myshell
myshell >>
```

the code is exec but not fork

```golang
    binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("/bin/bash")
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }

    args := []string{"/bin/bash"}

    env := os.Environ()

    execErr := syscall.Exec(binary, args, env)
    if execErr != nil {
        panic(execErr)
    }
```

so if I exit the bash shell, of course, my custom shell is killed.

```sh
myshell> bash
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
```

Comment: If you start in `myshell`, just `exec /bin/bash` (or equivalent for your shell), and when you are done in bash, just `exit` to get back to `myshell` (which you would have to make as a conditional in the command `/bin/myshell` so it is not executed on startup)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi, since I want replace my default shell in /etc/passwd, but if needed, I may need the bash shell. So I have to implement the feature that switch to  bash from my custom shell.

Comment: Oh... that makes more sense, but the same still works. If you boot to `/bin/myshell` and want to load `/bin/bash`, just do whatever `exec /bin/bash` is in `myshell` (which replaces your current shell with `/bin/bash`). To get back to `/bin/myshell` you would still only need to exit `/bin/bash`. I do that going from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/zsh` and back using only `alias zshell='(exec zsh)'` in my `.bashrc`. (but note `zsh` is executed in a *subshell* of my current shell, e.g. `(zsh)` preserving, e.g. putting to sleep, `/bin/bash` until I exit `zsh`)

Comment: @David C. Rankin The operation you said is just what I want to implement, but I am still looking for a way to fork the bash process in go language.

Comment: That part I am clueless about `:(` I've never even looked at what go is. Hopefully others can help there...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Once you `exec` you can't go back with `exit` (you could `exec` though). The new process _replaces_ the old.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson -- that is why when switching to `zsh` above, the `exec zsh` is done in a subshell, e.g. `(exec zsh)` so `zsh` replaces the subshell and exit returns control to the parent.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Simply invoking `zsh` does the same thing - no subshell needed.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - Not so. At the command prompt, enter `(exit)`, and then just `exit`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: of course _that's_ not the same thing. In the first you're exiting from the subshell and in the second you're exiting from the primary shell. And you're not using `exec` here. Try this: for each of `zsh`, `(zsh)` and `(exec zsh)` run one of those commands followed by (in Linux) `ps fT` (or in MacOS: `ps -f -t $(tty)`) then `exit`. In each of the three cases on either OS you will see that the ouput of `ps` indicates that the instance of `zsh` is a child of the parent shell (which is still present) and that there are no other intervening processes are running. You will also ...

Comment: ... notice that the `exit` brings you back to the parent shell. Thus, there is no point in using `exec` in a subshell and the only point of using a subshell would be if you're trying to preserve some state that you want to return to when the child exits (`$PWD` for example, if your child includes a `cd` at the top level - that is, outside a script or something). Oh, and the `exit` in your last comment is a shell builtin, by the way, so it isn't handled the same as a separate executable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recipe for how to stop a process and let the parent shell process take over control. I'm not sure if you can use it to do the opposite.

The idea is to send a stop signal to yourself.

```
pid := os.Getpid()
process, err := os.FindProcess(pid)
if err != nil {
    err = errors.Wrapf(err, "error pausing process %+v", process)
    return
}
process.Signal(syscall.SIGSTOP)
```

Source https://github.com/grzegorz-zur/bare-minimum/blob/95fb116631b6146707c47455d8ffce6bb5b8717c/editor.go#L152

Earlier you need to listen in a goroutine to continue signal to reinitialize your process if needed

```
signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(signals, syscall.SIGCONT, syscall.SIGTERM)
for signal := range signals {
    switch signal {
    case syscall.SIGCONT:
        // reinitialize
    case syscall.SIGTERM:
        // stop
    }
}
```

Source https://github.com/grzegorz-zur/bare-minimum/blob/95fb116631b6146707c47455d8ffce6bb5b8717c/editor.go#L87

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by this way.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "bash")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    cmd.Run()
}
```

Comment: Can you please also add explanation?